# Tips and tricks for VS2005 specifically for C# developers

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2005

Let's get the duplication allegation out of the way.

I saw couple of variations of this question, notably, [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15779/what-are-the-best-unknown-features-of-visual-studio-net-2005). However, it doesn't address issue specific to C# developers. I want to collect a list most used/powerful/cool tricks--tips in VS from people who are using C# under visual studio 2005 (it's ok to mention for 2008 as well). Below are the links that I have used as a guide:

[msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb245788(VS.80).aspx)  <-- our guys from Microsoft have a tip or two to share

[Kirill's Visual Studio Tips](http://blogs.msdn.com/kirillosenkov/archive/2008/10/21/kirill-s-visual-studio-tips.aspx)     <-- This blog also has couple of good links

*Debugging tips are also encouraged*

Thank for sharing your tips and increasing my productivity :)

**Some of my arsenal:**

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd>, navigates back and forward where you've been recently
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, which will cycle through your clipboard history
- <kbd>F12</kbd> to go to definition of variable.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to comment a block of text with // at the start
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>U</kbd> to uncomment a block of text with // at the start
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd> to get to the find box.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> for incremental search, <kbd>F3</kbd> to iterate
- Select an expression/variable in debug mode and type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> to open the quick watch window.

Comment: This is community wiki material.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you seen [this blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/saraford/archive/tags/Visual+Studio+2008+Tip+of+the+Day/default.aspx)... and the [book "Microsoft Visual Studio Tips"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735626405) that came from it?

Comment: Nice.... I think I saw this website, in passing

Answer (score 4):

Here is a site I just found last week
http://scottcate.com/tricks/

The #1 tip I have is go buy Resharper!

Comment: I came to C# from Java, and Resharper adds almost everything I miss from IDEa

Comment: what does it add? I don't want to pay for extra tricks unless they are REALLY worthwhile and mandatory to have

Comment: This video (http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/documentation/presentation/codingSession/CodingSession.wmv) is a pretty good illustration of the sorts of things you can do with Resharper if you know how to use it.  And it doesn't even address Resharper's invaluable code-quality features.

Comment: it seems to gain lots of support...greatzzz

Comment: It adds refactoring support, navigation, code analysis, and auto-completion, plus really nice custom templates.  I recently had to dev something without R# and I can't believe how long it took me!  Simple things like extracting interfaces, changing signatures, and renaming are so nice with R#!

Answer (score 2):

One of my favorite Snippets is the one for enums.

Say you have this code:

```
private void DoSomethingForToday(DayOfWeek today)
{
   //in here you want to do something different depending on which day it is, so you need a switch/case
   //you type switch, hit tab twice, you'll get this:

            switch (switch_on) //switch_on will be highlighted, replace it with "today" and hit enter. It will automatically fill in all the possible enum values with case statements.
            {
                default:
            }    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The tab key for "snippets"

e.g. type 'try' and then hit the tab key twice.

Results in:

```
try 
{           

}
catch (Exception)
{

    throw;
}
```

which you can then expand.

Comment: yep... I love this one, works for for lopps, if statements, etc...

Answer (score 1):

CTRL +ALT + P to attach a process,

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl-W, Ctrl-A -> to focus on the immediate window (the window itself is underused IMO).
of (filename) in the immediate window to open a file. You get nice path/name completion amongst all files in the solution.
Ctrl-W, Ctrl-S -> to foucs on the solution explorer.
Select an expression/variable in debug mode and type Ctrl-D,Ctrl-Q to open the quick watch window.

Answer (score 0):

See here at [StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9033/hidden-features-of-c).

Don't let the url fool you: the 'friendly' url strips off the # symbol.  This is the #3 highest voted question on StackOverflow, BTW, so it's not like it was exactly hidden.

Comment: Thanks, I saw this one  -- it is too general for my needs.